# How to check if one location coordinates fall to another location coordinates radius in android

Tags: android, gps, location, distance

I have latitude and longitude of a current location. I want to check if target location (latitude and longitude) is close with 50 meter radius to the current location.

I am new to android.if anyone have solution about this.please reply.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use the built in distance calculation:

```
Location loc;
.....
float radius = 50.0;
float distance = loc.distanceTo(loc2);
if (distance < radius) then inside.
```

Comment: is Radius in meters?